# Is document image binarization a closed research field

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, adaptive-algorithms, thresholding, optical-char-recognition

A lot of work has been done in the field of document image binarization. Is it a closed research field or still an interesting challenge area? I am new in the field, and just curious.

Answer (score 1):

First, in science, a field is rarely closed, sometimes asleep only. Resistance to low-contrast, real-time, badly  scanned, composite documents/writers or from aging medium seem to remain challenges, in similarity with other digital data: robustness, speed, poor acquisition, source separation or error concealment (the same topics, with generic names) are common for other data source.

As many data fields, this domain is being pervaded by [(deep) learning techniques threatening the old handcraft](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/26698/15892) (eg [Learning Document Image Binarization from Data](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.00529), Yue Wu *et al.*,  2015).

[DIBCO](https://vc.ee.duth.gr/dibco2017/) 2017, the [ICDAR 2017 Document Image Binarization COmpetition](https://vc.ee.duth.gr/dibco2017/), is still on, a good sign altogether, and a source of challenges.7

As a personal note, I have been very interested in the analysis of old written documents, and their authentification, based on:

- binarization from alternative light sources (multispectral, X-ray, ultraviolet), especially to detect previously scrapped, washed off  or erased writings, like from [palimpsests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palimpsest) ([Binarization of MultiSpectral Document Images](http://ttps://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-23117-4_10), 2015)
- accurate analysis of non-written elements like the [texture of paper fabric](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIM.2010.2069850)