# How to reconstruct a sound from magnitude spectrogram?

Tags: fourier-transform, audio, frequency-spectrum

I have an audio magnitude spectrogram but I don't have the phase, try to randomize the phases of each container and then make a reverse fourier, but only pure noise is heard

How can I reconstruct the phase information so that the audio is heard somewhat decent.

Anyone know an algorithm that does this?

Comment: I know that if you use a Gaussian window there is a direct mathematical relationship between magnitude and phase.  I’ve done the paper derivation before but it was years ago.  Maybe someone here knows of a reference to the relationship?

Answer (score 1):

In general the whole complex Fourier transform is needed to reconstruct the time domain signal.

However, it's possible to reconstruct a **real** signal it from its Fourier transform magnitude alone (or phase alone) by using some iterative techniques, or very large matrix solutions.

Have a look at the papers by Monson Hayes...

Answer (score 1):

Your question is at the heart of a still-current topic in signal processing or image analysis, often under the names *phaseless recovery*  or *phase retrieval*.

For instance, in January 2019, Yoshiki Masuyama *et al.* published a paper on *phase recovery from amplitude spectrograms*: [Griffin-Lim like phase recovery via alternating direction method of multipliers](https://doi.org/10.1109/LSP.2018.2884026) (Signal Processing Letters). Once again, [deep learning kicked in data processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/26698/15892): the Yoshiki Masuyama *et al.* published a conference paper (ICASSP 2019, May) on [Deep Griffin–Lim Iteration](https://doi.org/10.1109/ICASSP.2019.8682744).

Some Matlab code is provided on Yoshiki Masuyama web page, with the abbreviation [ADMMGLA --- alternating direction method of multipliers (ADMM) and Griffin–Lim algorithm (GLA)](https://sites.google.com/view/yoshiki-masuyama/admmgla).

You can find older references, with keyword "spectrogram inversion", like the [Phase Retrieval Toolbox](http://ltfat.github.io/notes/ltfatnote045_poster.pdf) for [LTFAT, the The Large Time-Frequency Analysis Toolbox](http://ltfat.github.io/).

Comment: actually the basic exact algorithm for signal recovery from phase alone (or magnitude vice versa) is quite old & simple and I have it implemented in my matlab. But it requires a very large matrix solution... Hence, new iterative techniques are investigated instead possibly.

Comment: Implementing the basic version is something I should have done, which I did not. Which reference did you use?

Comment: From the book 2D signal and image processing Jae S Lim ch.1 gives a definition...

Comment: here the link: http://i65.tinypic.com/15p3mv9.jpg

Comment: Retrieved, excellent